# AutoIt's "WinActivate" function doesn't recognize window

Tags: autoit

I have a problem using AutoIt to identify a window; it has no title, the class isn't helpful, and the handle changes every time the window reopens. How can I identify it?

It is the 'save' dialog for the [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) browser, on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to identify by Text?

Comment: Yes, but the title is blank and doing so didn't help.

Comment: ".. doing so didn't help" .I'm astonished. Based on text identification you can get the handle (Wingethandle()) and you can use all Win Management functions you could use based on title. So for what it didn't help?

Comment: @ReFran So teach me. What would you do in that case? I guess i am really that stuck that i can't get pass this.

Comment: You didn't tell what you want to achieve! $handle = Winwait("","myText")should be a good startup. Have a look at this example under ControlSend, that may be include all statements you need: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm. More you will find in the help file under Windows Management. Good luck.

Comment: I am trying to get a hold on the window. As i can't use click on the buttons, i will use the window's location to move the mouse and simulate a left click on 'save' button. What text can i use?

Comment: I am trying to use "ControlGetHandle" but the control doesn't have neither an ID not a text, and it's class isn't helpfull.

Comment: Even tried using Windows' Inspect.exe, but didn't find any useful details i can use to get a hole on the window \ control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AutoItSetOption('WinTitleMatchMode',4)
WinWaitActive("[TITLE:; CLASS:WebViewWindowClass1]", "")
```

Comment: Thanks, i managed to bypass it by activating another window which caused the required one to be in focus..